# Best practice to store price changes over time in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `Nestjs` and `Mongoose` as **ODM**. I have a model called Product which has the following properties:

**Product Model**

```
    @Schema({ timestamps: true, id:true, toJSON:{virtuals:true} })
    export class Product {
       @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
       title: string

       @Prop({ type: String })
       brand: string

       @Prop({ type: String })
       description: string


       @Prop({ type: Number})
       currentPrice: number

    }
```

every 4 hours product price will get updated. I'm wondering what's the best way to store product price history in `MongoDB`. in a SQL database like `PostgreSQL`, we make a ProductPrice table with (productId, price, date). But as `MongoDB` max document size is 16MB and thousands of products that I have& what is the best solution in `MongoDB`??

Comment: Have you tried out your ProductPrice schema? I don't foresee any specific difficulty. The 16 MB document size limit is for a single document (or equivalent to a row in RDBMS), so I guess you are not likely to reach the limit for the 3-field schema you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not challenging for `MongoDB` feel free and just create a `ProductHistory` collection for that:

```
{
  id: ObjectId,
  product_id: ObjectId,
  created_at: Date,
  price: 99,
  currency: "$",
  expiration: 4,
  expired: false
}
```